# Add to pdf custom html without adding it to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using an angular app, I should export a page in pdf format.

The template expected on the pdf in not the same as the webpage.

For that I would create a custom html then use html2canvas to convert html to image that i add to pdf file.

My problem here is that should call `document.getElementById();` on an existing html to be able to convert it to image.

but these custom html element should not appear in the webpage.

**What I'm expecting :** I would like to know how can I add custom html to pdf without add it to the body of my html page.

My workaround is to show custom html only when click on export to pdf

**Html page**

```
  <div id="filters" *ngIf="exportPdfService.inExport">
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">..</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">..</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">..</span>
  </div>
```

Then in my **Ts**

```
exportPDF() {
    this.exportPdfService.inExport = true;
    const elm = this.logoActivity.nativeElement.src;
    const filtersElm = document.getElementById('filters');
    const logo = html2canvas(filtersElm).then(canvas => {
        pdf.addImage(canvas, 'png', 150, 45, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        pdf.save(`file_.pdf`);
    });
}
```

But when exporting is on process elements are visible.

I'm looking for a way to create custom html "in background"

Comment: Draw it offscreen

Comment: What does it mean exactly

Comment: You can add css transform with something like translateX with a negative value larger than the width of you div like -1000px. You add content in the DOM to this div. But it is at -1000px to the left and therefore not seen.